# Legendre Transformation of the functional $F=(\phi(x))^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, dirac-delta

I've been asked as a Homework to find Legendre Transform of the functional $F[\phi(x)]=\phi^n(x)$ $(i.e. (\phi(x))^n)$.

If  Legendre transform control function be $J(x)$, then I know that the L.T. functional $G[J]$ is given by

$$G[J]=\int \phi(x')J(x')dx'-F \tag{1}$$
This is how I proceeded -
$$J(y)=\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi(y)}$$
$$\Rightarrow J(y)=n\phi^{n-1}(x)\delta(x-y)\tag{2}$$
$$I=\int \phi(x')J(x')dx'=\int n\phi(x')\phi^{n-1}(x)\delta(x-x')dx'$$
$$\Rightarrow I=n\phi^n(x)\tag{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow G[J]=n\phi^n(x)-\phi^n(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow G[J]=(n-1)\phi^n(x)\tag{4}$$
To express this in terms of $J(y)$ I'm thinking (naively) to invert (2) as -
$$\phi^n(x)=\biggl(\frac{J(y)}{n\delta(x-y)}\biggr)^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\tag{5}$$
So
$$G(J(y))=(n-1)\biggl(\frac{J(y)}{n\delta(x-y)}\biggr)^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\tag{6}$$

I'm highly doubtful that this is correct since I've never seen Dirac delta in the denominator. What is the correct way to invert expressions like (2), OR, How to express $G$ in terms of $J$ correctly?

Comment: You write $F[\phi(x)]=\phi^n(x)$. Is $x$ fixed in the right hand side?

Comment: Echoing @md2perpe, it would be more natural if the functional was defined as $F[\phi]=\int dx~\phi^n(x)$.

Comment: Yes @md2perpe.Think of F as taking the function $\phi(y)$ as input and spitting out a number which is the value of $\phi(y)$ at $y=x$.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Eqs. (5) & (6) do not make sense mathematically.

Comment: @Qmechanic. That's why the he doubts that his result is correct.